# D3: Animate pie chart update

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I'm trying to animate an update in my pie chart using d3.js. I've tried using the attrTween function, but cannot seem to get it working properly.

```
function updatePieChart() {
    $.when(someOtherAjaxFunction()).done(function (json) {
        for (x in json) {
            var npath = d3.select('svg' + x).selectAll("path").data(pie(json))
            npath.transition().duration(1000).attrTween("d", arcTween); // redraw the arcs
        }

        function arcTween(a) {
            var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
            this._current = i(0);
            return function (t) {
                return arc(i(t));
            };
        }
    })

} //updatePieChart
```

Any help is much appreciated.

- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2k548m0/3/)

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410)?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it. Couldn't seem to adjust it.